# Kyle Simpson's OLOO Pattern vs Prototype Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Does Kyle Simpson's "OLOO (Objects Linking to Other Objects) Pattern" differ in any way from the the Prototype design pattern? Other than coining it by something that specifically indicates "linking" (the behavior of prototypes) and clarifying that there's no to "copying" happening here (a behavior of classes), what exactly does his pattern introduce?

Here's [an example of Kyle's pattern](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md#delegation-theory) from his book, "You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes":

```
var Foo = {
    init: function(who) {
        this.me = who;
    },
    identify: function() {
        return "I am " + this.me;
    }
};

var Bar = Object.create(Foo);

Bar.speak = function() {
    alert("Hello, " + this.identify() + ".");
};

var b1 = Object.create(Bar);
b1.init("b1");
var b2 = Object.create(Bar);
b2.init("b2");

b1.speak(); // alerts: "Hello, I am b1."
b2.speak(); // alerts: "Hello, I am b2."
```

Comment: Can you at least link to a description of the pattern you're asking about.  Even better would be to show a code example of it in your question.

Comment: Getify is on Stackoverflow sometimes. I've tweeted him this question :)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

> what exactly does his pattern introduce?

OLOO embraces the prototype chain as-is, without needing to layer on other (IMO confusing) semantics to get the linkage.

So, these two snippets have the EXACT same outcome, but get there differently.

**Constructor Form:**

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.y = 11;

function Bar() {}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.z = 31;

var x = new Bar();
x.y + x.z;  // 42
```

**OLOO Form:**

```
var FooObj = { y: 11 };

var BarObj = Object.create(FooObj);
BarObj.z = 31;

var x = Object.create(BarObj);
x.y + x.z;  // 42
```

In both snippets, an `x` object is `[[Prototype]]`-linked to an object (`Bar.prototype` or `BarObj`), which in turn is linked to third object (`Foo.prototype` or `FooObj`).

The relationships and delegation are identical between the snippets. The memory usage is identical between the snippets. The ability to create many "children" (aka, many objects like `x1` through `x1000`, etc) is identical between the snippets. The performance of the delegation (`x.y` and `x.z`) is identical between the snippets. The object creation performance *is* slower with OLOO, but [sanity checking that](http://web.archive.org/web/20141012195436/http://blog.getify.com/sanity-check-object-creation-performance) reveals that the slower performance is really not an issue.

What I argue OLOO offers is that it's much simpler to just express the objects and directly link them, than to indirectly link them through the constructor/`new` mechanisms. The latter pretends to be about classes but really is just a terrible syntax for expressing delegation (**side note:** so is ES6 `class` syntax!).

**OLOO is just cutting out the middle-man.**

Here's [another comparison](https://gist.github.com/getify/d0cdddfa4673657a9941) of `class` vs OLOO.

Comment: I found really interesting your answer and the idea of OLOO desribed in your books, I would like have your feedback on this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395762/oloo-how-to-access-private-variable

Specially if you found this implementation correct and how to solve issue related to access private member. Thanks for your time in advance and congratulation for your latest book.

Comment: But `Object.create(...)` is many times slower than `new`. http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-crockford-vs-jorge-vs-constructor/62

Comment: @Pier the performance is not actually that much of a problem. fixed the broken blog post link about sanity checking the performance of object creation, which explains how to properly think about this.

Comment: And jQuery is slower than the DOM API, right? But, it's the current year, man - I'd rather write elegantly and simply than worry about optimizing. If I need to micro-optimize later, I'll worry about it when the time comes.

Comment: I would like to add that now, just over a year later, Object.create() is heavily optimized in chrome, and that jsperf shows it--it's one of the fastest options now. This shows exactly why you shouldn't concern yourself with such micro-optimizations, and instead just write algorithmically sound code.

Answer (score 27):

I read Kyle's book, and I found it really informative, particularly the detail about how `this` is bound.

### Pros:

For me, there a couple of big pros of OLOO:

#### 1. Simplicity

OLOO relies on `Object.create()` to create a new object which is `[[prototype]]`-linked to another object. You don't have to understand that functions have a `prototype` property or worry about any of the potential related pitfalls that come from its modification.

#### 2. Cleaner syntax

This is arguable, but I feel the OLOO syntax is (in many cases) neater and more concise than the 'standard' javascript approach, particularly when it comes to polymorphism (`super`-style calls).

### Cons:

I think there is one questionable bit of design (one that actually contributes to point 2 above), and that is to do with shadowing:

> In behaviour delegation, we avoid if at all possible naming things the same at different levels of the `[[Prototype]]` chain.

The idea behind this is that objects have their own more specific functions which then internally delegate to functions lower down the chain. For example, you might have a `resource` object with a `save()` function on it which sends a JSON version of the object to the server, but you may also have a `clientResource` object which has a `stripAndSave()` function, which first removes properties that shouldn't be sent to the server.

The potential problem is: if someone else comes along and decides to make a `specialResource` object, not fully aware of the whole prototype chain, they might reasonably* decide to save a timestamp for the last save under a property called `save`, which shadows the base `save()` functionality on the `resource` object two links down the prototype chain:

```
var resource = {
  save: function () { 
    console.log('Saving');
  }
};

var clientResource = Object.create(resource);

clientResource.stripAndSave = function () {
  // Do something else, then delegate
  console.log('Stripping unwanted properties');
  this.save();
};

var specialResource = Object.create( clientResource );

specialResource.timeStampedSave = function () {
  // Set the timestamp of the last save
  this.save = Date.now();
  this.stripAndSave();
};

a = Object.create(clientResource);
b = Object.create(specialResource);

a.stripAndSave();    // "Stripping unwanted properties" & "Saving".
b.timeStampedSave(); // Error!
```

This is a particularly contrived example, but the point is that specifically *not* shadowing other properties can lead to some awkward situations and heavy use of a thesaurus!

Perhaps a better illustration of this would be an `init` method - particularly poignant as OOLO sidesteps constructor type functions. Since every related object will likely need such a function, it may be a tedious exercise to name them appropriately, and the uniqueness may make it difficult to remember which to use.

<sub>*Actually it's not particularly reasonable (`lastSaved` would be much better, but it's just an example.)</sub>

Comment: I agree that the potential for name collisions is a drawback... but actually it's a drawback of the `[[Prototype]]` system itself, not OLOO specifically.

Comment: Perhaps that should have been mentioned in the book as well?

Comment: I'm not really sure this is really a solution to the problem @Ed Hinchliffe describes since it just moves save() to it's own namespace but it does work https://codepen.io/tforward/pen/govEPr?editors=1010

Comment: I think @ed-hinchliffe meant `b.timeStampedSave();` instead of `a.timeStampedSave();` on last line of the code snippet.

Comment: @tristan-forward thank you for bringing Rick and Morty into this!

Answer (score 14):

The discussion in "You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes" and the presentation of the OLOO is thought-provoking and I have learned a ton going through the book. The merits of the OLOO pattern are well-described in the other answers; however, I have the following pet complaints with it (or am missing something that prevents me from applying it effectively):

**1**

When a "class" "inherits" another "class" in the classical pattern, the two function can be declared similar syntax (["function declaration" or "function statement"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function)):

```
function Point(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

function Point3D(x,y,z) {
    Point.call(this, x,y);
    this.z = z;
};

Point3D.prototype = Object.create(Point.prototype);
```

In contrast, in the OLOO pattern, different syntactical forms used to define the base and the derived objects:

```
var Point = {
    init  : function(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
};


var Point3D = Object.create(Point);
Point3D.init = function(x,y,z) {
    Point.init.call(this, x, y);
    this.z = z;
};
```

As you can see in the example above the base object can be defined using object literal notation, whereas the same notation can't be used for the derived object. This asymmetry bugs me.

**2**

In the OLOO pattern, creating an object is two steps:

1. call `Object.create`
2. call some custom, non standard method to initialize the object (which you have to remember since it may vary from one object to the next):

   ```
    var p2a = Object.create(Point);

    p2a.init(1,1);
   ```

In contrast, in the Prototype pattern you use the standard operator `new`:

```
var p2a = new Point(1,1);
```

**3**

In the classical pattern I can create "static" utility functions that don't apply directly to an "instant" by assigning them directly to the "class" function (as opposed to its `.prototype`). E.g. like function `square` in the below code:

```
Point.square = function(x) {return x*x;};

Point.prototype.length = function() {
    return Math.sqrt(Point.square(this.x)+Point.square(this.y));
};
```

In contrast, in the OLOO pattern any "static" functions are available (via the [[prototype]] chain) on the object instances too:

```
var Point = {
    init  : function(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    },
    square: function(x) {return x*x;},
    length: function() {return Math.sqrt(Point.square(this.x)+Point.square(this.y));}
};
```

Comment: There are no literals in your first code example. You are probably misusing the "literal" term giving it another meaning. Just saying...

Comment: Regarding the 2nd point, the author argues that it is a "better" separation of concern to have creation and initialization separate and cites there might be some rare use case where this may shine (example an object pool). I find the argument terribly weak.

Comment: Again regarding the 2nd point, with OLOO, you can create your objects at one time, and wait to initialize, whereas with the constructor, you have to initialize on creation, so Kyle considers this a benefit.

Comment: @IvanKleshnin "an object literal is a comma-separated list of name-value pairs wrapped in curly braces". The object `{init: function(x,y) ..}` that's assigned to var `Point` in the second part of the 1st example is an object literal in my book.

Answer (score 4):

> "I figured to do it makes each obj dependent on the other"

As Kyle explains when two objects are `[[Prototype]]` linked, they aren't really 
dependent on each other; instead they are individual object. You're linking one 
object to the other with a `[[Prototype]]` linkage which you can change anytime you wish. **If you take two `[[Prototype]]` linked objects created through OLOO style as being dependent on each other, you should also think the same about the ones created through `constructor` calls.**

```
var foo= {},
    bar= Object.create(foo),
    baz= Object.create(bar);


console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)) //Object.prototype

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)) //foo

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(baz)) //bar
```

Now think for a second do you think of `foo` `bar` and `baz` as being dependent on each-other?

Now let's do the same this `constructor` style code-

```
function Foo() {}

function Bar() {}

function Baz() {}

Bar.prototype= Object.create(Foo);
Baz.prototype= Object.create(Bar);

var foo= new Foo(),
    bar= new Bar().
    baz= new Baz();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)) //Foo.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype)) //Object.prototype

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)) //Bar.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Bar.prototype)) //Foo.prototype

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(baz)) //Baz.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Baz.prototype)) //Bar.prototype
```

The only difference b/w the latter and the former code is that in the latter one 
`foo`, `bar`, `baz` bbjects are linked to each-other through arbitrary objects 
of their `constructor` function (`Foo.prototype`, `Bar.prototype`, `Baz.prototype`) but in the former one (`OLOO` style) they are linked directly. Both ways you're just linking `foo`, `bar`, `baz` with each other, directly in the former one and indirectly in the latter one. But, in both the cases the objects are independent of each-other because it isn't really like an instance of any class which once instantiated, can't be made to inherit from some other class. You can always change which object an object should delegate too.

```
var anotherObj= {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, anotherObj);
```

So they're all independent of each-other.

> " I was hoping `OLOO` would solve the issue in which each object knows
>   nothing about the other."

Yes that's indeed possible-

Let's use `Tech` as an utility object-

```
 var Tech= {
     tag: "technology",
     setName= function(name) {
              this.name= name;
}
}
```

create as many objects as you wish linked to `Tech`-

```
var html= Object.create(Tech),
     css= Object.create(Tech),
     js= Object.create(Tech);

Some checking (avoiding console.log)- 

    html.isPrototypeOf(css); //false
    html.isPrototypeOf(js); //false

    css.isPrototypeOf(html); //false
    css.isPrototypeOf(js); //false

    js.isPrototypeOf(html); //false
    js.isPrototypwOf(css); //false

    Tech.isPrototypeOf(html); //true
    Tech.isPrototypeOf(css); //true
    Tech.isPrototypeOf(js); //true
```

Do you think `html`, `css`, `js` objects are connected to each-other? No, they aren't. Now let's see how we could've done that with `constructor` function-

```
function Tech() { }

Tech.prototype.tag= "technology";

Tech.prototype.setName=  function(name) {
              this.name= name;
}
```

create as many objects as you wish linked to `Tech.proptotype`-

```
var html= new Tech(),
     css= new Tech(),
      js= new Tech();
```

Some checking (avoiding console.log)-

```
html.isPrototypeOf(css); //false
html.isPrototypeOf(js); //false

css.isPrototypeOf(html); //false
css.isPrototypeOf(js); //false

js.isPrototypeOf(html); //false
js.isPrototypeOf(css); //false

Tech.prototype.isPrototypeOf(html); //true
Tech.prototype.isPrototypeOf(css); //true
Tech.prototype.isPrototypeOf(js); //true
```

How do you think these `constructor`-style Objects (`html` , `css`, `js`) 
Objects differ from the `OLOO`-style code? In fact they serve the same purpose. In `OLOO`-style one objects delegate to `Tech`(delegation was set explicitly)  while in `constructor`-style one objects delegate to `Tech.prototype`(delegation was set implicitly). Ultimately you end up linking the three objects, having no linkage with each-other, to one object, directly  using `OLOO`-style, indirectly using `constructor`-style.

> "As is, ObjB has to be created from ObjA.. Object.create(ObjB) etc"

No, `ObjB` here is not like an instance (in classical-based languages) of any class 
`ObjA`. **It sould be said like `objB` object is made delegate to `ObjA` object at it's creation 
time"**. If you used constructor, you would have done the same 'coupling', although indirectly by making use of `.prototype`s.

Comment: I've got to laugh. This was one funny and pointless comparison, so much work that didn't make any sense. All those comparisons between html, css, js just didn't make any sense...

Answer (score 3):

@Marcus @bholben

Perhaps we can do something like this.

```
    const Point = {

        statics(m) { if (this !== Point) { throw Error(m); }},

        create (x, y) {
            this.statics();
            var P = Object.create(Point);
            P.init(x, y);
            return P;
        },

        init(x=0, y=0) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    };


    const Point3D = {

        __proto__: Point,

        statics(m) { if (this !== Point3D) { throw Error(m); }},

        create (x, y, z) {
            this.statics();
            var P = Object.create(Point3D);
            P.init(x, y, z);
            return P;
        },

        init (x=0, y=0, z=0) {
            super.init(x, y);
            this.z = z;
        }
    };
```

Of course, creating a Point3D object that links to the prototype of a Point2D object is kind of silly, but that's beside the point (I wanted to be consistent with your example). Anyways, as far as the complaints go:

1. The asymmetry can be fixed with ES6's [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) or
   the more frowned upon `__proto__ = ...` that I use. We can also use [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) on regular objects now too, as seen in `Point3D.init()`. Another way would be to do something like

   ```
   const Point3D = Object.assign(Object.create(Point), {  
       ...  
   }
   ```

   though I don't particularly like the syntax.

---

2. We can always just wrap `p = Object.create(Point)` and then `p.init()` into a constructor. e.g. `Point.create(x,y)`. Using the code above we can create a `Point3D` "instance" in the following manner.

   ```
   var b = Point3D.create(1,2,3);
   console.log(b);                         // { x:1, y:2, z:3 }
   console.log(Point.isPrototypeOf(b));    // true
   console.log(Point3D.isPrototypeOf(b))   // true
   ```

---

3. I just came up with this hack to emulate static methods in OLOO. I'm not sure if I like it or not. It requires calling a special property at the top of any "static" methods. For example, I've made the `Point.create()` method static.

   ```
       var p = Point.create(1,2);
       var q = p.create(4,1);          // Error!
   ```

Alternatively, with ES6 [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) you can safely extend Javascript base classes. So you could save yourself some code and define the special property on Object.prototype. For example,

```
    const extendedJS = {};  

    ( function(extension) {

        const statics = Symbol('static');

        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, statics, {
            writable: true,
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: true,
            value(obj, message) {
                if (this !== obj)
                    throw Error(message);
            }
        });

        Object.assign(extension, {statics});

    })(extendedJS);


    const Point = {
        create (x, y) {
            this[extendedJS.statics](Point);
            ...
```

---

Answer (score 2):

@james emanon - So, you are referring to multiple inheritance (discussed on page 75 in the book "You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes"). And that mechanism we can find in underscore's "extend" function for example. Names of object you stated in your example are a bit mixing apples, oranges and candies but I understand the point behind. From my experience this would be OOLO version:

```
var ObjA = {
  setA: function(a) {
    this.a = a;
  },
  outputA: function() {
    console.log("Invoking outputA - A: ", this.a);
  }
};

// 'ObjB' links/delegates to 'ObjA'
var ObjB = Object.create( ObjA );

ObjB.setB = function(b) {
   this.b = b;
}

ObjB.setA_B = function(a, b) {
    this.setA( a ); // This is obvious. 'setA' is not found in 'ObjB' so by prototype chain it's found in 'ObjA'
    this.setB( b );
    console.log("Invoking setA_B - A: ", this.a, " B: ", this.b);
};

// 'ObjC' links/delegates to 'ObjB'
var ObjC = Object.create( ObjB );

ObjC.setC = function(c) {
    this.c = c;  
};

ObjC.setA_C = function(a, c) {
    this.setA( a ); // Invoking 'setA' that is clearly not in ObjC shows that prototype chaining goes through ObjB all the way to the ObjA
    this.setC( c );
    console.log("Invoking setA_C - A: ", this.a, " C: ", this.c);
};

ObjC.setA_B_C = function(a, b, c){
    this.setA( a ); // Invoking 'setA' that is clearly not in ObjC nor ObjB shows that prototype chaining got all the way to the ObjA
    this.setB( b );
    this.setC( c );
    console.log("Invoking setA_B_C - A: ", this.a, " B: ", this.b, " C: ", this.c);
};

ObjA.setA("A1");
ObjA.outputA(); // Invoking outputA - A:  A1

ObjB.setA_B("A2", "B1"); // Invoking setA_B - A:  A2  B:  B1

ObjC.setA_C("A3", "C1"); // Invoking setA_C - A:  A3  C:  C1
ObjC.setA_B_C("A4", "B2", "C1"); // Invoking setA_B_C - A:  A4  B:  B2  C:  C1
```

It is simple example but the point shown is that we are just chaining object together in rather flat structure/formation and still have possibility to use methods and properties from multiple object. We achieve same things as with class/"copying the properties" approach. Summed by Kyle (page 114, "this & Object Prototypes"):

> In other words, the actual mechanism, the essence of what’s important
>   to the functionality we can leverage in JavaScript, is **all about objects
>   being linked to other objects**.

I understand that more natural way for you would be to state all the "parent" (careful :) ) objects in one place/function call rather modeling whole chain.

What it requires is shift in thinking and modeling problems in our applications according to that. I'm also getting used to it. Hope it helps and final verdict from the Kyle himself would be great. :)

Comment: Yeah -- thanks -- but I was hoping to move away from this methodology because the way you have it, and the way I figured to do it makes each obj dependent on the other..  I was hoping OLOO would solve the issue in which each object knows nothing about the other. As is, objB has to be created from ObjA.. Object.create(ObjB) etc.. that is too coupled. any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

@Marcus, just like you, I have been keen on OLOO and also dislike the asymmetry as described in your first point.  I've been playing with an abstraction to bring the symmetry back.  You could create a `link()` function that is used in place of `Object.create()`. When used, your code could look something like this...

```
var Point = {
    init  : function(x,y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
};


var Point3D = link(Point, {
    init: function(x,y,z) {
        Point.init.call(this, x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }
});
```

Remember that `Object.create()` has a second parameter that can be passed in.  Here is the link function that leverages the second parameter.  It also allows a little bit of custom configuration...

```
function link(delegate, props, propsConfig) {
  props = props || {};
  propsConfig = propsConfig || {};

  var obj = {};
  Object.keys(props).forEach(function (key) {
    obj[key] = {
      value: props[key],
      enumerable: propsConfig.isEnumerable || true,
      writable: propsConfig.isWritable || true,
      configurable: propsConfig.isConfigurable || true
    };
  });

  return Object.create(delegate, obj);
}
```

Of course, I think @Kyle would not endorse shadowing the `init()` function in the Point3D object.  ;-)

Comment: In looking back through this, I now think that by combining `Object.assign()` with `Object.create()`, we can greatly simplify the `link()` function above.  In its place, we could use this: `function create(delegate, props) { return Object.assign(Object.create(delegate), props); }`.  Or better yet, we can use Underscore or Lodash to make it really concise:  `_.create(delegate, props)`.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a way to OLOO more than "two" objects.. all the examples I consist of the based example (see OP's example). Lets say we had the following objects, how can we create a "fourth" object that has the attributes of the 'other' three? ala...

```
var Button = {
     init: function(name, cost) {
       this.buttonName = name;
       this.buttonCost = cost;
     }
}

var Shoe = {
     speed: 100
}

var Bike = {
     range: '4 miles'
}
```

these objects are arbitrary, and could encompass all sorts of behaviors. But the gist is, we have 'n' number of objects, and our new object needs something from all three.

instead of the given examples ala:

```
var newObj = Object.create(oneSingularObject);
    newObj.whatever..
```

BUT, our newObject = (Button, Bike, Shoe)......

What is the pattern to get this going in OLOO?

Comment: This sounds like "favor composition over inheritance" - a great strategy.  In ES6, you can use `Object.assign()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign.  If writing in ES5, you can use Underscore's `_.extend()` or Lodash's `_.assign()`.  Here's an excellent video to explain... https://youtu.be/wfMtDGfHWpA.  If you have any colliding properties, the last one wins - so order matters.