# Get the properties of the function object

Tags: javascript

I am learning object oriented javascript, from [Object Palyground](http://www.objectplayground.com/)

according to the tutorial, function itself is considered as an object and i know that you can get the properties of an object using **in** keyword in javascript

```
var obj = {a:"hello",b=123};
for(var prop in obj)
alert(var);
```

The above code gives me the keys present in the **function object obj** as expected

but when I use the same code for this situation

```
var funObj = function(a,b){
   alert("hello");
}
for(var prop in funObj)
alert(prop);
```

or in this case even

```
function myFunction(a,b){
 alert("hello");
}
for(var prop in myFunction)
alert(prop);
```

It does not give me any output, Ideally according to the tutorial the function object should comprise of **three properties that are: name, length and prototype** but i am getting none, where i am doing wrong

kindly help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where i am doing wrong

`for...in` only iterates over **enumerable** properties. The default properties of native objects are often non-enumerable.

You could use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get a list of properties of the function object:

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(function() {})
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype"]
```

Or if you just want to inspect the properties for learning purposes, use `console.dir` to log the function:

[image]

Comment: One more query, If i understand correctly when you say ENUMERABLE properties does that mean that the user defined ones instead of native ones?

Comment: Not necessarily. By default, properties created through assignment, e.g. `foo.bar = 42;` are enumerable. However, you can also create non-enumerable properties via `Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {value: 42, enumerable: false});`. So, "enumerability" really is a characteristic of every property.

Comment: Thanks again, I am from Java background so these concepts are little confusing to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {a:"hello",b=123};
```

if not the same as

```
var obj = function(a, b) {}
```

If you want A and B to be properties, you should do it that way:

```
var obj = function(a, b) {
   this.a = a;
   this.b = b;
}
```

That way, obj.a and obj.b make a little more sense, but not that much yet.
function(){} is you constructor. So you need to actually build an instance in order to use it the right way.

```
var myObj = new obj('value for a', 'value for b');
for (var prop in myObj) {
   // Prop = a || b
   console.log(prop);

   // Values for a and b
   console.log( myObj[ prop ] );
}
```

If you use it in a static way, you do NOT have to do the function thing.
Also not that object don't have the length method. Arrays do.

To make this REALLY SIMPLE, and totally not accurate, {} (objects) are kinda static and function(){} are instanciable (does that word even exists?), which means you can use the "new" and therefore benefit from the function constructor.

This is all really technic, and it looks like you're beginning with javascript. Tell me if I was unclear or you need some precision.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Bene, Thanks for the quick response, I am good in Java and not that comfortable with javascript i am trying to learn the object oriented concepts, According to the javascript documentation

Answer (score 0):

A `Function` in JavaScript can be referred to as "first class" as it is a *callable object* meaning it is an object with callable semantics added to it. In some ways an `Array` in JavaScript is similar to a `Function` in that they are both objects but have special features included. *NOTE: A common statement uttered about JavaScript is that ["everything is an object"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+"everything+is+an+object") but this is not true however. None of the **simple primitives** (`string`, `boolean`, `number`, `null`, and `undefined`) are objects (although JS does some nifty tricks if you attempt to treat them as such).*

```
var obj = {bar: 'hi'};
Object.keys(obj); // ["bar"]

function func() {}
Object.keys(func); // []
func.bar = 'hello';
Object.keys(func); // ["bar"];

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
Object.keys(arr); // ["0", "1", "2"]
arr.bar = 'hey';
Object.keys(arr); // ["0", "1", "2", "bar"]
```

`bar` shows up in all three because those properties are set to be [**enumerable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) by default. However as you noted a function has some other properties but those aren't showing up. Why? Let's look at `obj` first.

```
obj.propertyIsEnumerable('bar'); // true
```

`bar` by default was set to be `enumerable`.

Now lets look at `bar` in `func`.

```
func.propertyIsEnumerable('bar'); // true
```

So that explains why `bar` shows up for `func` but what about `name`?

```
func.propertyIsEnumerable('name'); // false
```

Ahah! It is not enumerable. This is true for a lot of properties/methods that are automatically linked to or assigned to an object via the JavaScript engine. For instance, the `length` property of an array object.

```
arr.propertyIsEnumerable('length'); // false
```

That all said, if you are new to JS I would highly recommend reading the ***You Don't Know JS*** series by [Kyle Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228852/kyle-simpson). It's meant for people with some programming experience but they are very useful for learning what JS is and what it's not (no matter how much syntactic sugar gets piled on). **I would especially recommend focusing on the key point of the difference between classical inheritance and JavaScript's [*OLOO (Objects Linking to Other Objects).*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468602/3194372)**

The intro book [**Up & Going**](http://amzn.to/1SdE9gH) is a quick read that covers the basics of what the entire series will dive deeper into. The rest of the series (so far) includes: [**Types & Grammar**](http://amzn.to/1IPqf3V), [**Scopes & Closures**](http://amzn.to/1M02EiF), [***this* & Object Prototypes**](http://amzn.to/1IPqo7n), [**Async & Performance**](http://amzn.to/1gszKuL), and [**ES6 & Beyond**](http://amzn.to/1TqpT6U). You can also preview them all on his [github repository](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS).

**OR** You can also review MDN's documentation for [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for some very good information.