# OLOO how to access private variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

In the following example I am using Kyle Simpson's "OLOO (Objects Linking to Other Objects) Pattern" to create a simple example of object serialization.

I need to keep variable `_data` private (I am using a closure) and expose its properties only with getter and setters which are create on object instance level (in `init`).

Currently I defined function `toJson` inside `init` so it can access `_data` and it works but, I would like to know:

- If would be possible to move `toJson` function outside `init`(place it at same level of `fromJson`) so it will accessible via protoype chain but allowing to access `_data` variable (I suspect it is not possible because `_data` it is in a closure).
- Otherwise could you suggest a better alternative(even using ES6) keeping in consideration that `_data` should not be enumerable and not modifiable apart using getter and setter?

```js
        // example of serialization and deserialization of an object
        (function (window) {
            var dataApi = '{"id":0,"top":10,"left":20,"width":100,"height":150}';
            var state = JSON.parse(dataApi);
            var base = {
                init: function (data) {
                    var _data = data; // private
                    // defined on object itself not on its protoype
                    Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', {
                        get: function () {
                            return _data.id;
                        },
                        set: function (value) {
                            _data.id = value;
                        }
                    });
                    Object.defineProperty(this, 'top', {
                        get: function () {
                            return _data.top;
                        },
                        set: function (value) {
                            _data.top = value;
                        }
                    });
                    Object.defineProperty(this, 'left', {
                        get: function () {
                            return _data.left;
                        },
                        set: function (value) {
                            _data.left = value;
                        }
                    });
                    Object.defineProperty(this, 'width', {
                        get: function () {
                            return _data.width;
                        },
                        set: function (value) {
                            _data.width = value;
                        }
                    });
                    Object.defineProperty(this, 'height', {
                        get: function () {
                            return _data.height;
                        },
                        set: function (value) {
                            _data.height = value;
                        }
                    });
                    this.toJson = function () {
                        // move this function to prototype
                        return JSON.stringify(_data);
                    }
                },
                // defined on protoype
                fromJson: function (json) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(json),
                        obj = Object.create(this);
                    obj.init(data);
                    return obj;
                }
            };

            // create object with linked prototype using deserialization
            var wdgA = base.fromJson(dataApi);
            // serialize object
            var str = wdgA.toJson();
            console.log(str);

            // create object with data injection
            var wdgB = Object.create(base);
            wdgB.init(state);
            var id = wdgB.id;
            console.log(id);
        })(window);
```

Comment: In case question is not clear, please add a comment I do my best to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Make _data non-enumerable private object property. There's no security in JS and there's no reason to be zealous about encapsulation.

Comment: @estus How would he/she make it private ?

Comment: @Taurus I'm not sure what you mean. `_` prefix is conventional in JS to mark private properties that shouldn't be accessed externally under normal circumstances. They can be non-enumerable to not appear in property lists accidentally.

Comment: @estus In your case, does he/she add that `_foo` property directly to the object, like: `var obj = {_foo: "bar"};`, and then make it `enumerable: false` ?

Comment: @Taurus More like `Object.defineProperty(obj, '_foo', { value: 'bar', configurable: true, writable: true })`. `enumerable` is done by default.

Comment: Yes, that is more efficient, but i i was too lazy to do that in a comment. So, do you think your version of private property is better than OP's ?

Comment: @Taurus Because a variable in the OP isn't a prop. It's a variable. It cannot be accessed from the outside to be reflected. The purpose of encapsulation is to help a developer, not to create obstacles. There is no true OOP visibility in JS, and so there are no situations where it would be really handy for security reasons, because JS isn't compiled language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to keep variable `_data` private (I am using a closure). Would it be possible to move `toJson` function outside `init`?

No. Private variables cannot be accessed from outside.